# How do I install vue router plugin with Vue CLI 3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

So I've been setting up projects with the Vue CLI 3.0.0rc8 and it is a pretty awesome tool but I have a problem. I am trying to install the router plugin for my project however when I use `vue add router`, I get this:

```
(node:2706) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'routerHistoryMode' of undefined
at module.exports (/home/joshua/programs/firstwebapp/frontend/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/generator/router/index.js:10:26)
at Generator.plugins.forEach (/home/joshua/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/Generator.js:96:7)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at new Generator (/home/joshua/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/Generator.js:94:13)
at Function.runGenerator (/home/joshua/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/invoke.js:111:21)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:2706) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2706) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Could someone please explain why this isn't working?

**P.S.** I've also tried `vue add @vue/router` and I get the same message.

Comment: Are you in the root of the project when you do that command 'vue add router'? Error doesnt give much of clue whats going on.

Comment: @josip Yes I made sure that I was in the root directory. I feel like this may be a bug with the vue CLI.

Comment: @JoshuaAvery yes seem to be right, i'we created new project with Vue cli 3.0.0rc3 and i get the same error when trying to 'vue add router'.

Comment: @josip I've figured it out and I posted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it! Thank you to @dnhyde for your suggestion. But if you actually want to install it as a plugin you need to update the Vue CLI to 3.0.0-rc.10. Do so with this command: `npm i -g @vue/cli`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had a similar issue, the best way to add Vue router in my case was to select it from the start with `vue create my-project` command. Or you can manually add the router.js file and the `Vue.use(router)` in your main following the template vue-cli creates for you.

Comment: Where would I find the router.js file? Would I  `npm install vue-router`? However wouldn't this be loading the library used with the older CLI? Would I be able to find the actual CLI 3 plugin source somewhere? Or is there any difference?